# Need help to write a shell script to calculate the directory space used & free

Tags: unix

I need help to write a shell script to calculate the directory space in tabular format.the output will contain the used space,total space & the free space.Please kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the command "df".  Unfortunately, the output and options depend on whatever flavor of UNIX you happen to be using.

Type "man df" or try "df -h" on a command line to learn more.

Here's an example from my Mac:

```
kim-burgaards-macbook-pro:~ kim$ df
Filesystem    512-blocks       Used Available Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   976101344  912544576  63044768    94%    /
devfs                224        224         0   100%    /dev
map -hosts             0          0         0   100%    /net
map auto_home          0          0         0   100%    /home
/dev/disk1s1   976773104  761379976 215393128    78%    /Volumes/Photo Vault
/dev/disk2s2  1952853344 1844058136 108795208    95%    /Volumes/Backup
```

As far as I remember, the output looks very similar on Solaris.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, directories don't have a notion of total space and free space, that depends on the disk the directory resides on.

To know the space used you can use `du -s 'directory name'`.

You can use `df 'Directory name'` to find the available space on that storage media and probably combine the two.

For example, consider the directory '~/Desktop'

```
[foo@bar ~] df -h ~/Desktop
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
foobar:/vol/arbit/foo
                      126G   84G   43G  67% /home/foo
```

Clearly `~/Desktop` has not used 84G,

```
[foo@bar ~] du -sh ~/Desktop
30M     /home/foo/Desktop
```

which is the correct usage.

You can use `awk` to grab required fields and populate your information.